# every value is a Object... want to delete first column pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

If I try to print any value of the data frame I'm getting an Object (id value). I just want the value in the data frame.

I've tried removing the first column (df[0]), but that's removes the date column...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display the `values` of a specific `column` of a `DataFrame` :

```py
df['Start Time'].values.tolist()
```

To refresh the `index`, you can use :

```py
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

And to change the type of a specific column (to `int`/`float`/`str` ...) :

```py
df['column_name'] = df['column_name'].astype(int)
```

Comment: Thank you, but the thing is that I would like to delete that "id" from the dataframe or make all the values from the df as "string", "int" , etc. not an object combined of "id value" or at least reorder the ID's

Comment: `df.reset_index(drop=True)` let you refresh the index. To change the type of a column, you can try `df['column_name'].astype(int)`.

Comment: Does this answer help you ?

Comment: mm more or less, manually yes, I think there is not a form to change the actual type to ("int", "string", or whatever automatically depending on how it detects)